# Forgot to include --with-curl when configuring PHP.  How to add without disrupting other extensions?

Tags: php, configure

If I compile PHP 5 from source and realize I forgot a `--with-curl` in it, can I run the same `./configure` command and add `--with-curl` at the end and it will add it?  Or can I just do `./configure --with-curl` and it will add it to the everything that is already installed?

Answer (score 5):

You have to reconfigure and then recompile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to added it to the end of your old configuration like this

```
./configure --with-something1 --with-something2 --with-curl
```

Comment: So if I do something like ./configure --with-something --withs-something2 --with-curl  and then do make and make install and realize I don't want --with-something   Can i just then do ./configure --with-something2 --with-curl and it will remove --with-something??

Comment: @mahle Exactly, just remember `make install` need root privileges.

Comment: Ummm I might be late to this party but dont forget to run make after configure. You *always* need to run make after configure then make install after that.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `./configure` (previous command + new addition), `make`, `make install`, `make clean`.

Answer (score 1):

`./configure` doesn't remember the parameters you last used to call it, although you can fish them out of `config.status` if you have forgotten them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the correct configure command and compile using the make command. If you wane more information about autoconf see http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/#introduction basically ./configure just sets up the build and you can change options using it.